# How do I trace the source of the call "OnValidate()"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want a script to have radio buttons for booleans and it seems like `OnValidate()` would be the perfect way to do that. However, i would need to trace what value was changed in the inspector and put a check for the identifier but I couldn't find the solution for the tracing part. How do i know what value was changed for `OnValidate()` to be called?

Comment: somewhere store the values as fields and compare them to the current values I guess. anyway [`OnValidate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html) is only issued by changes via the Inspector within the Unity Editor .. not later in your built app: `This function is called when the script is loaded or a value is changed in the Inspector (Called in the editor only).`

Comment: Yeah I know it's for the editor. I needed it to learn to avoid logical errors. Furthermore if I set another bool in the inspector to true, then in OnValidate(), both checks [If (bool1) {//toggle other bools to false} - if (bool2) {//toggle other bools to false] will be true and it will just execute the first true check. So I can't compare the values either.

Comment: yeah but as said you could have `bool1`, `bool2`, `_oldbool1`, `_oldbool2` and then do `if(bool1 != _oldbool1) { /*bool1 was changed*/ } if(bool2 != _oldbool2) { /*bool2 was changed*/ }` etc

Comment: I don't think that would work because the old bools will automatically get new values assigned before OnValidate() is called. (Since it is only called when something is changed and in this case, there are already 2 true bools before the call)

Comment: But the `_old` values only get assigned within this `OnValidate` method .. they wouldn't be serialized fields so they have the last value before the change was invoked ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comments might not be the most "beautiful" solution but I would do it e.g. like

```
// These are the fields in the Inspector
// changing any via the Inspector will Invoke OnValidade
[SerializeField] private bool bool1;
[SerializeField] private bool bool2;

// These are private and will be used to check what was changed
private bool _oldBool1;
private bool _oldBool2;

private void OnValidate()
{
    if(bool1 != _oldBool1)
    {
        // bool1 was changed 

        if(bool1)
        {
            // Probably: set all other values to false
        }
        else
        {
            // Probably check if all other values are false, if so this may not be false
        }
    }

    if(bool2 != _oldBool2)
    {
        // bool2 was changed 

        if(bool2)
        {
            // Probably: set all other values to false
        }
        else
        {
            // Probably check if all other values are false, if so this may not be false
        }
    }

    // Etc

    // And finally store the new values


    _oldBool1 = bool1;
    _oldBool2 = bool2;

    // Etc
}
```

Afaik the changes via script of the serialized fields should not Invoke another [`OnValidate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html), only changes via the Inspector or the first time the asset is loaded.

> This function is called when the script is loaded or a value is changed in the Inspector (Called in the editor only).

You could probably also work with a List/Array instead of individual fields of course

---

*Typed on smartphone so can't test it right now but I hope the idea gets clear*